# Java FX setOnAction not doing anything

Tags: java, javafx, tree, treeview

I'm developing a project for college where i need to do a Personal File System using a ADT Tree.

Currently i can open the folder and all the elements of the folder are added to the tree and displayed in a TreeView in Java FX. I can rename the files, edit the files and display the file content. However, when i try do create a new File or new Folder pressing that option in my context Menu, nothing happens.

I tried adding the logic of the renameFile inside the createFile and still nothing happens, same the other way around.

This is the code of my class.

```
    public void createFolder() {

        createFolder.setOnAction(event -> {
            File dir = getValue();
            if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
                return;
            }

            String dirName = dialogHandler.showTextInputDialog("Nova Pasta", "A criar    nova pasta", "Por favor insira o nome da pasta:", "pasta");
            if (dirName == null) {
                return;
            }

            File file = new File(dir, dirName);

            if (file.exists()) {
                dialogHandler.showAlert(AlertType.WARNING, "Aviso", "A pasta: " + file.getName() + " já existe",
                        "Não foi possível criar a pasta pois já existe uma com o mesmo nome");
            } else {
                boolean success = file.mkdir();
                if (!success) {
                    dialogHandler.showAlert(AlertType.ERROR, "Erro",
                            "Erro a criar diretório: " + file.getName(),
                            "Não foi possível criar o diretório especificado");
                } else {
                    // Adicionar à TreeLinked
                    Position<File> parentPosition = treeLinked.isInternal(treeLinked.root()) ? treeLinked.root() : null;
                    Position<File> insertedPosition = treeLinked.insert(parentPosition, file);

                    // Adicionar à TreeView existente
                    TreeItem<File> newTreeViewItem = new TreeItem<>(file);
                    treeView.getRoot().getChildren().add(newTreeViewItem);

                    // Expande o nó pai na TreeView para mostrar a nova pasta
                    treeView.getRoot().setExpanded(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is createFolder? Can you put a system.out into the method to verify it is executed or not? If it is executed, I would suggest, that you are running into a "if -> return".

Comment: createFolder is my method to create folders in the file system. I Have tried putting a sout however it is not even exectued

Comment: createFolder can't be a method. If it is a method, how can it execute .setOnAction()?

Comment: You have a method createFolder() and a variable "createFolder". Is everything linked correct?

Comment: i have a method createFolder using a setOnAction which by the sound of it it is probably the wrong way to do it, however everything is linked in the contextMenu by the variable variable "createFolder"

Comment: public ContextMenu createContextMenu() {

   menuItems.add(refresh);
   menuItems.add(createFile);
   menuItems.add(createFolder);
   menuItems.add(deleteFile);
   menuItems.add(renameFile);
   menuItems.add(editFile);
   menuItems.add(viewFile);
   menuItems.add(fucnaoTeste);
   createFile();
   createFolder();
   refreshTree();
   deleteFileTree();
   renameFile();
   editFile();
   viewFileContent();
   fucnaoTeste(); //Puramente para debugging e testes


   return contextMenu;
 }

Comment: Create and post a [mre].

Comment: "menuItems.add(createFolder);": This method has an object as Parameter called createFolder, NOT a method. Your method "public void createFolder()" is never called in that code. Do you need to call the method in your init() to initialize the listener on an object, whose variable is called "createFolder" too?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to refactor your code, including renaming your variables to something "that are something", and your methods to something "that does something".

Comment: I have solved this issue, I did a major refactor on the code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:**

```
// Somewhere in your controller:
private Class? createFolder;

// Somewhere in your initConstructorOrWhatever method:
public initConstructorOrWhatever(){
    initCreateFolder();
}

public void initCreateFolder() {
    createFolder.setOnAction(event -> {
        File dir = getValue();
        if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
            return;
        }
        // ... Code
    });
}
```

**Note:**

If you want to be a good programmer, I recommend you too read this book (no sponsoring):

[image]